# Wordpress custom rewrites

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to make custom rewrite rule like this:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    'sample-list/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$',
    'index.php?pagename=sample-list&custom_var=matches[1]',
    'top' 
);
```

In sample-list I have some list with links.

I also have page sample-list which is template where I generate these links. And link looks like this: `http://test.local/sample-list/whatever-111`
So in this situation I can't access custom_var, It's empty.

The only way I managed to work around this is to create custom post type with different name than page. Now structure looks like this:

List: `http://test.local/sample-list` (page)

Single item: `http://test.local/sample-list-item/whatever-111` (sample-list-item is a custom post type)

I can't create custom post type with same name as page name.

So my goal is:

List: `http://test.local/sample-list`

Single item: `http://test.local/sample-list/whatever-111`

And custom_var would be `111`

Comment: please add full code of the custom post type

Comment: I actually don’t want to use cpt.

Comment: Because content of inner kist item is comming from API

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following code with above code you  can read the full documentation 
[Wordpress Rewrite_API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule#Using_rewrite_rules_to_redirect_to_scripts_other_than_index.php)

```
function custom_rewrite_tag() {
  add_rewrite_tag('%custom_var%', '([^&]+)'); 
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked:

```
add_filter('generate_rewrite_rules', 'generate_rewrite_rules');

function generate_rewrite_rules($wp_rewrite) {
    $wp_rewrite->rules = array_merge(
        ['sample-list/[^/]*\D(\d+)/?$' => 'index.php?some_id=$matches[1]'],
        $wp_rewrite->rules
    );
}
```